# Ubuntu 15.04 freezing on shutdown/reset and having problem with Nvidia

Tags: nvidia, shutdown

I've just installed ubuntu 15.04 on my laptop (Asus N56JR).
I noticed that when i click on reset/shutdown my computer freezes and it wont turn off. I waited for too long, But nothing happened.
I also install nvidia-340 [propreitary] driver on my system alongside nvidia-settings-server for switching between Nvidia and Intel, but after rebooting, It went to low graphics mode and after loging into my account it went to  black screen and everything freezed. I even couldn't go to tty mode.

My laptop has no such problems with kernel 3.13, but in 3.19, it seems like it can not use my laptop's nvidia graphics card and just works on Nouveau display driver.
I really need a fix for this issue, cause my laptop is much faster and smoother on kernel 3.19.x but it lags on 3.13 .

Answer (score 0):

Just install laptop-mode-tools to solve shutdown freeze problem:

```
sudo apt-get install laptop-mode-tools
```

If you have tlp installed on your system, you must remove it because it's conflicting with laptop-mode-tools:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge tlp tlp-rdw
```

Comment: Didn't worked for me.