# Cannot shutdown or reboot after upgrading from 14.10 to 15.04 on Intel NUC

Tags: shutdown, intel, reboot

I have been running ubuntu 14.04, then 14.10 on my Intel NUC model DN2820FYKH for months without any issues. I recently reformatted and reinstalled a fresh copy of 15.04, and after doing so I am now unable to reboot or shutdown, via terminal or from the GUI. Upon doing either, I get the purple loading screen, and there it stays. One difference I've noticed is that while shutting down, the progress bars appear to move for a while before freezing. When rebooting, they never move at all. I have to go to the box, hold down the power button, then turn it back on.

So far I have run all updates, and tried the following solution:

[Ubuntu 15.04 freezing on shutdown/reset and having problem with Nvidia](https://askubuntu.com/questions/613019/ubuntu-15-04-freezing-on-shutdown-reset-and-having-problem-with-nvidia)

This appears to be the same issue:

[14.10 to 15.04 upgrade, now I can't poweroff or reboot!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/616861/14-10-to-15-04-upgrade-now-i-cant-poweroff-or-reboot)

update: I tried adding `acpi=force` to my grub file as detailed here:

[Shutdown does not power off computer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125844/shutdown-does-not-power-off-computer)

This did not fix the issue.

Comment: try to add this `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX='acpi_enforce_resources=lax'` to GRUB and then run `sudo update-grub`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Still not fixed, although now I can see that the freeze occurs after "reached target shutdown." A quick Google search seems to show that my intel NUC bios just doesn't recognize the shutdown command being issued, although it worked on previous ubuntu versions. I tried the latest BIOS update from intel, which is only a week or so old, but same result.

Comment: in this case if it's might be a bug you could post it to [Launchpad](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug) also.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do the following for the NUC model DN2820FYKH

Update the BIOS to version FYBYT10H.86A.0055

[download the update from Intel here](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/26318/BIOS-Update-FYBYT10H-86A-?wapkw=dn2820fykh)

Then add  `reboot=bios` as a boot parameter:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Find the line that begins `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=` and change it to:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash reboot=bios"
```

Save and exit, and run

```
sudo update-grub
```

Then reboot. This worked on Xubuntu 16.10 for me.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

Reboot only worked between the BIOS update and a poweroff. After that one poweroff and restart, reboot no longer works. Updated BIOS does not fix the issue.

I am now using this script to force a reboot if really needed (its a development machine)

```
#!/bin/bash

service mysql stop
service apache2 stop

sync
sleep 1
sync
sleep 1

echo 1 > /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq
echo b > /proc/sysrq-trigger
```

---

old bad answer follows.

I had this same problem with this NUC model: NUC DN2820FYKH

Upgrading to version 52 of FYBYT10H.86A BIOS fixed the problem.

Download link: https://downloadcenter.intel.com/es/download/25448/Actualizaci-n-de-BIOS-FYBYT10H-86A-

Comment: UPDATE:

I downgraded the newer-bios NUC to kernel 3.13.0-24 and it now reboots just fine.
 
Maybe an incompatibility between newer BIOSes and newer ubuntu kernels?